# SQL Query get total value based on different unit price,quantity at different time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transaction table that like this: quantity is the total quantity in stock based on different unit price. let's call it T

```
id | transaction_time | item | unit_price | quantity | subtotal
1      2012-5-15          A         1.00         15         15.00
2      2012-5-15          A         3.00         15         45.00
3      2012-5-15          B         1.00         10         10.00
4      2012-6-10          A         2.00         15         30.00
5      2012-6-15          A         2.00         10         20.00
```

I need to get the total value of each item in stock over time...however, same items are based on different unit price. The result for A for example is:

```
transaction_time | item |  quantity | subtotal
    2012-5-15          A     30         60.00
    2012-6-10          A     45         90.00
    2012-6-15          A     40         80.00
```

2012-5-15, we have 15 item A with price 1.00, 15 item A with price 3.00, so the total quantity is 30, subtotal is 15*1+15*3=60.

2012-6-10 we have 15 more item A with price 2, so the total quantity become 30+15=45, subtotal become 60+15*2=90

2012-6-15 we have 10 item A with price 2, so item A with price 2 goes down from 15 to 10. the total quantity become 40, and the subtotal goes down -2*5, which become 80.

I tried

```
select transaction_time,sum(quantity),sum(subtotal)
where id in(select max(id) from T group by unit_price,item)
group by item
having item=A
```

This only gives me the last line

```
2012-6-15          A     40         80.00
```

Comment: What did you try? Also, I'm struggling to understand the arithmetic

Comment: The result set for `A` on `2012-6-10` and `2012-6-15` do not match with the input data provided, at least not in any obvious way. Can you please provide an explanation about how quantity values of `45` and `35` are obtained?

Comment: updated explanation.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos  updated explanation..

Comment: It seems to me that there's nothing in the data which indicates that totals should be incremented or decremented - is there some sort of implied logic that's not in the question?

Comment: A challenging question, I like it and working on it @weeo

Comment: @Muhammadvakili yes it is...I added the unit price into the existing table and tried to see the inventory level change I used to have before. Then I have this challenging question.

Comment: @P.Salmon it is based on item and unit price. those 2 works as the primary key to keep track of the quantity of which item with that unit price

Comment: It's not challenging. It's just bonkers.

Comment: @Strawberry help!

Comment: So if the quantity is less than the previous quantity totals should go down?

Comment: I'm not medically qualified

Comment: @P.Salmon yes! the entry with same item and unit price overrides the previous entry

Comment: I also find it challenging. Actually it is the most challenging question I've answered for months.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I tried not to make another table to store those information. But it turns out it is pretty hard to query...

Comment: Yes, I think the complexity of the query hints toward a redesign of your schema.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos my goal is to maintain the history of quantity and total value in one table for items with different unit price. I think it will be easier than maintaining 2 tables...

Answer (score 1):

Following query(kind of complex, maybe slow, needs optimization) works, check [DEMO](http://rextester.com/SVZKT61506)

```
SELECT tr_sub.cur_tt, tr_sub.item, sum(tr.quantity), sum(tr.quantity*tr.unit_price) 
FROM 
  (SELECT tr1.transaction_time as cur_tt, max(tr2.transaction_time) as prev_tt, tr1.item as item, 
     IF (tr1.unit_price=tr2.unit_price, tr1.unit_price, tr2.unit_price) as t_p 
     FROM transactions tr1 LEFT JOIN transactions tr2 ON 
     tr1.transaction_time>=tr2.transaction_time AND tr1.item=tr2.item
    GROUP BY tr1.item, tr1.transaction_time,  t_p
   ) as tr_sub INNER JOIN transactions tr ON 
   tr_sub.prev_tt=tr.transaction_time 
   AND tr_sub.item=tr.item 
   AND tr_sub.t_p=tr.unit_price
GROUP BY tr_sub.item, tr_sub.cur_tt
ORDER BY tr_sub.cur_tt, tr_sub.item
```

Comment: I can't see your changes in the link, you have to fork it change it and create a new code wall.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry about that. Check **[this](http://rextester.com/YPHZ66712)**. Look at record `16.06.2012 A 15 2`. Value of `15` is wrong because it is not the most current for this `unit_price`.

Comment: I have updated the solution, it should fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

You need first to identify all possible `unit_price` values for the specific item:

```
SELECT DISTINCT unit_price
FROM t
WHERE item = 'A'
```

**Output:**

```
unit_price
----------
1
3
2
```

You also need to identify all possible `transaction_times`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT transaction_time
FROM t
WHERE item = 'A';
```

**Output:**

```
transaction_time
----------------
2012-05-15
2012-06-10
2012-06-15
```

Now perform a `CROSS JOIN` between the above two sets

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT transaction_time
   FROM t
   WHERE item = 'A') AS times
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT unit_price
   FROM t
   WHERE item = 'A') AS up
ORDER BY times.transaction_time
```

to get:

```
transaction_time unit_price
----------------------------
2012-05-15       3
2012-05-15       2
2012-05-15       1
2012-06-10       3
2012-06-10       2
2012-06-10       1
2012-06-15       1
2012-06-15       3
2012-06-15       2
```

Now use the above and perform a correlated subquery to get `unit_price` per `transaction_time` from item `'A'`:

```
SELECT transaction_time, unit_price,
       (SELECT quantity
        FROM t
        WHERE t.item = 'A' 
              AND t.unit_price = up.unit_price
              AND t.transaction_time <= times.transaction_time
        ORDER BY transaction_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS quantity
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT transaction_time
   FROM t
   WHERE item = 'A') AS times
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT unit_price
   FROM t
   WHERE item = 'A') AS up
ORDER BY times.transaction_time
```

**Output:**

```
transaction_time     unit_price  quantity
----------------------------------------
15.05.2012 00:00:00  1           15
15.05.2012 00:00:00  3           15
15.05.2012 00:00:00  2           NULL
10.06.2012 00:00:00  1           15
10.06.2012 00:00:00  3           15
10.06.2012 00:00:00  2           15
15.06.2012 00:00:00  1           15
15.06.2012 00:00:00  3           15
15.06.2012 00:00:00  2           10
```

The final result is simply a matter of performing a `GROUP BY` on the above:

```
SELECT transaction_time, 
       'A' AS item,
       SUM(quantity) AS quantity,
       SUM(quantity*unit_price) AS subtotal
FROM (           
    SELECT transaction_time, unit_price,
           (SELECT quantity
            FROM t
            WHERE t.item = 'A' 
                  AND t.unit_price = up.unit_price
                  AND t.transaction_time <= times.transaction_time
            ORDER BY transaction_time DESC LIMIT 1) AS quantity
    FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT transaction_time
       FROM t
       WHERE item = 'A') AS times
    CROSS JOIN (
       SELECT DISTINCT unit_price
       FROM t
       WHERE item = 'A') AS up) AS x
GROUP BY transaction_time
```

**Output:**

```
transaction_time  item  quantity  subtotal
----------------------------------------------
15.05.2012        A     30        60
10.06.2012        A     45        90
15.06.2012        A     40        80
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/GDKVM28670)